# grep 2 elements in a line and print them

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Here is my issue, i have a file with the entries, i would like to get just the date + the last command after the last "]: "

```
Aug 17 14:25:17 snaper[22134]: [ip:10.1.15.245 37985 10.1.15.18 22 uid:10000 sid:21680 tty: cwd:/data/www/hybris/hybris/bin/platform filename:/bin/ps]: /bin/ps -p 6763
```

How can i get it when i cat the file ?

I can get the date with:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'
```

and the last command with :

```
awk -F': ' '{print $NF}'
```

But how to combine them to get it in a single line ? 
I'm not awk limited, any sed grep or other command is ok for me :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Just remove everything between the date and the last command:

```
sed 's/^\(... .. ..:..:..\).*: /\1 /'
```

Comment: It looks like a braille transcription.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using AWK

```
$awk '{print $1,$2,$3,  $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF }' file
Aug 17 14:25:17 /bin/ps -p 6763
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU grep

```
grep -oP '^.{15}|.*\]: \K.*' file | paste - -
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible use `tee` for use 1 output to 2 commands:

```
echo 'Aug 17 14:25:17 snaper[22134]: [ip:10.1.15.245 37985 10.1.15.18 22 uid:10000 sid:21680 tty: cwd:/data/www/hybris/hybris/bin/platform filename:/bin/ps]: /bin/ps -p 6763' | tee >(awk -F': ' '{print $NF}') | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' | tr '\n' ' '
```

and we have output as:

```
Aug 17 14:25:17 /bin/ps -p 6763
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ s="Aug 17 14:25:17 snaper[22134]: [ip:10.1.15.245 37985 10.1.15.18 22 uid:10000 sid:21680 tty: cwd:/data/www/hybris/hybris/bin/platform filename:/bin/ps]: /bin/ps -p 6763"
```

Use `sed` to achieve your goal,

```
$ sed -r 's/(^.*:[0-9]{2}) .*]:/\1/' <<< "$s"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following solutions too. Considering your Input_file will be having same data as shown sample.

**Solution 1st:** Using simple cut command.

```
cut -d" " -f1,2,3,14,15,16  Input_file
```

**Solution 2nd:** using awk command where I am making string snaper and ]: as field separators.

```
awk -F' snaper|]:' '{print $1,$4}'  Input_file
```

**Solution 3rd:** making record separator as space and then printing only those lines which we need as per OP's request.

```
awk -v RS=" " 'NR<4||NR>13{printf("%s%s",$0,NR<3||NR<16?" ":"")}' Input_file
```

**Solution 4th:** Substituting everything from snap to till : and get whatever is OP's request.

```
awk '{sub(/snaper\[.*\]: /,"");print}'  Input_file
```

**Solution 5th:** Using --re-interval here(as I have old version of awk) you could remove it if you latest awk version in your system too.

```
awk --re-interval '{match($0,/.*[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}'  Input_file
```

**Solution 6th:** using sed and substituting everything till snaper and then everything till colon and printing the match only.

```
sed 's/\(.[^s]*\)\(.*:\)\(.*\)/\1\3/'   Input_file
```